# Импорт XML через Wp All Import и Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, xml, xpath, acf

Есть такой xml файл, в котором есть записи.

```
<post>
<Title>What Is Bigos? (Correct answer)</Title>
<Content>
<p>What is Bigos and how is it used?</p>
<ul>
<li>
As a dish that does not spoil quickly and only gets tastier with each reheating,
<b>bigos</b>
has been traditionally used as a provision for travellers and campers or consumed at outdoor events, such as a hunt [more]
</li>
</ul>
<h2>What is bigos called in English?</h2>
Bigos (Polish pronunciation: [ˈbʲiɡɔs]; Belarusian: і, bihas, or і, bihus, Lithuanian: bigusas), often translated into English as hunter's stew, is [more]
<h2>What does bigos taste like?</h2>
In 17
<sup>th</sup>
century cuisine, bigos was either made sour with vinegar, lemons, limes, or even with sorrel or gooseberries; made sweet with [more]
<p style="text-align: center;"></p>
<h2>How do you make bigos?</h2>
Bigos Recipe Cut your washed cabbage in thin slices and boil until tender in a pot. Boil the sauerkraut in [more]
<h2>How many calories are in a bigos?</h2>
Hunter's Stew Bigos (1 cup) contains 13g total carbs, 9g net carbs, 15g fat, 2g protein, and 180 calories.
<h2>Can bigos be frozen?</h2>
"Bigos " may be frozen so we can make a substantial quantity of the dish and store it in our [more]
<h2></h2>
My dad used to make hunter's stew but he called it kapusta, which means cabbage in Polish. Hunter's stew, also [more]
<h2>What is the national dish of Brazil?</h2>
Feijoada is a black bean stew that is brewed with a variety of salted and smoked pork and beef products [more]
<h2>What is the national dish of Poland?</h2>
Bigos stew is the national dish of Poland. It can be made with any kind of meat from pork to [more]
<h2>What is the Polish word for sauerkraut?</h2>
The real confusion comes in because, while each of these preparations may have their own proper (long) name, ( kapusta [more]
<h2>When was Bigos invented?</h2>
Sauerkraut, potatoes, bacon, and kielbasa are some of the additional ingredients which complete the dish. It has been present in [more]
<h2>What is haggis meat?</h2>
haggis, the national dish of Scotland, a type of pudding composed of the liver, heart, and lungs of a sheep [more]
</Content>
<category>Все кеи</category>
</post>
```

И есть в записях ACF поля, что-то вроде карточек. Я хочу в заголовок вносить h2, а в контент - весь текст, что идёт после h2.

Нужно хотя бы в заголовком разобраться. По идее, должно работать, но заголовок не загружается.
Но количество карточек верно - они формируются по количеству h2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Нет ли возможности переделать файл импорта, чтобы было 2 столбика - заголовок и контент?

В таком виде проблем быть не должно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, я думал об этом, но там таких постов более 1000.... Есть ли способ как-то автоматизировать это, вытащить контент и заголовок?

Comment: Вам нужен скрипт, к сожалению, не могу с этим помочь. Попробуйте создать новый вопрос, или заказать на фрилансе за несколько баксов.